# Windows 10, two monitors with two different sessions

Tags: windows-10, multiple-instances, graphics-processing-unit

I want to do some thing but I can't find anything about it. I remember that on Linux you can do a `multisit workstation` with one PC and several screens and perifericals (mouse, keyboard, etc), configuring X11 to serve different user sessions on different screens **with only one PC**.

I want to do the same or something similar on Windows 10. I need to have one user session on one screen and other user session on the other screen.

That's possible with **Windows 10 Creators Update**?

Maybe hardware is relevant:

- Intel i7 6700HQ 3.4GHz / RAM 32 GB DDR4 2133 MHz
- Intel HD Graphics 530
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060
- 2 minidisplay port, 2 HDMI port, USB-C

Thank you.

Comment: There is third-party software that will do this, but it _violates your license agreement_.

Comment: Closed after 1 year and 7 months active. This community right now is pure trash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Windows client operating system  does not support multiple interactive login at the same time, Terminal Server do.

The console session can't be splitted, it's a 1x1 relationship, terminal server or client operating system.

Comment: That's final sentence? Ok, so I don't want to install terminal server, impossible with windows. Thank you.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude A side note, depending on what the user do, I see more and more monitor with a builtin thinos/terminal that replace full computer. It could be a workaround

Comment: Ok, however I assume that Windows is still not a multiuser operating system. Yes, you can have several users, but you can't play them at same time (example: the music on one session, when you change to other session it stops). This is something that linux have by default, more powerful system no doubt.